# Find the first URL address from a webpage and use it as the redirect URL using JS

Tags: javascript, string, web, find, redirect

I would like to fetch this URL, which is **NOT** hyperlinked, from this contentless webpage. There are basically two strings embedded in it, a short text and the raw URL; Think of it as a text document, but in reality it is not. Example:

> [CLICK URL] http://www.example.com/

So, technically what I want to do is to use the URL for the redirect address and at the same time it excludes the short text from interfering. To sum it up, it fetches the URL from the webpage and blocks out the "[CLICK URL]" to be able to use the full URL as the redirect address.

I'm not too sure, but I think it should look something like this (incomplete and not working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var web = window.location.href + '?action=raw' // Where the text and URL are located
var txt = web.getElementById(element);
var range = web.createRange();
url = range.selectNodeContents(txt);
window.location.href = url // Used the provided URL for the redirect address
</script>
```

As you can see, this is an embedded script, an external script is strongly recommended. 
This has to work with any length of the URL and be cross-browsered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following function will accomplish your task.

Essentially, javascript will ignore all of the text, except for what you place within the  tag containing the id="MyDiv1". It then takes whatever is contained in that span tag, and tries to redirect to it.

As long as you place a valid url within that span tag, you should be redirected successfully. Nothing else on this page will interrupt this function, unless you create another element with the same ID, which will cause a conflict.

```
[CLICK URL] <span id="MyDiv1">http://www.example.com/</span>

 <script>
   var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('MyDiv1');
   url = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
   window.location.href = url
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried it and the redirect address came out as "}//]]>". Forgot to mention that I was hoping for an external script.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: @user2056671 Could you provide us with your browser version? I am unable to replicate your issue. Thanks!

Comment: @alanine I'm using Safari 5.1.5 (6534.55.3)

Comment: @alanine Nope, it outputs "}//]]>".

Comment: @alanine Oh never mind, it does work. Could you please make an external script? Because I don't have admin access to this webpage.

Comment: @user2056671 I have placed the .html file into a rar. However, I've already pasted the code, and explained it in my original comment. For a working .html file - as seen in the demo url, see: www.tdg.systems/s1.rar

Comment: @alanine This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I need it to be an external javascript file. Thanks for the example though.

Comment: @user2056671 I've updated the .rar file .. Just redownload - our check my demo, and grab the source code. :)

Comment: @alanine It seems to work, but somehow it's outputting: `%3Ca%20rel=%22nofollow%22%20class=%22external%20free%22%20href=%22http://www.example.com/%22%3Ehttp://www.example.com/%3C/a%3E` By the looks of it, is there a possible way to tell JavaScript that if there are two strings exactly the same, use the duplicate string as the url? Any method of removing this encoded data is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need an Ajax request. This is an example using jQuery:

```
<script>
// fetch the file via a jQuery Ajax request
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/test/file.htm",
    success : function(result){
        // get the <body> content of the file (split with regular expressions)
        var body = result.split(/<body[^>]*>/i)[1].split(/<\/body>/i)[0];
        // split the bits separated by space (" ") and redirect to the 2nd bit (the URL)
        window.location.href = body.split(" ")[1];
    }
});
</script>
```

Keep in mind that the file you want to fetch has to be on the same domain as yours. This means "example.com/..." will only work if the fetching script is also on this domain (cross domain requests are usually not allowed for security reasons).

Comment: I implemented it and doesn't do anything. I inserted the jQuery API from google and nothing happens. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I changed the code and now it should work (tested).